# How to get first value from NSMutableArray (iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, ios, arrays, nsmutablearray

Now i am working in simple iphone application, i have stored some value in `NSMutableArray` like  `"{54.399, 196}","{-268.246, 273}".`so i want to get 54.399 in first `indexpath`, how to get this, please help me

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is this a CGRect as NSString?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems you have an Array of Arrays, so it would be:

```
[[myArray objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Or using subscripting:

```
myArray[0][0];
```

---

**Edit**:

Ok you have an Array of `NSStrings`. To do what you want (get the 53.399) do the following:

```
NSString *myString = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *stringComponents = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSString *myFinalString = [stringComponents objectAtIndex:0];
```

With subscripting:

```
NSString *myFinalString = [[myArray[0] componentsSeparatedByString:@","][0];
```

Comment: NSLog(@"Testing:%@",[[Array objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:0]);

Comment: Error comes in -[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1084a950

Comment: Ok you have a NSString, just put:[myArray objectAtIndex:0]. To get that value you then have to manipulate the string

Comment: [[Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:0]

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
[[arrayObj objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0];
```